# How maven pom.xml identifies the testng test cases in a non-standard project structure?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, testng, pom.xml

I am completely new to maven and testng. I am using maven as build tool, and testng as my testing framework. I am not following the standard maven project structure. Now I want my `pom.xml` to execute the test cases in my project. The question is, how `pom.xml` knows what are the test cases to consider for execution?

Comment: You question is ok, you got the downvote because of your writing quality. If you want success on such forums like this, you need to fix that very fast.

Comment: @Peter Horvath thanks for your valuable suggestion. Initially  I wondered why my reputation score reduced.Thanks for the clarification too.Henceforth,I wish my writing quality would be good.

Comment: What's the reason not to follow the maven default folder layout?

Comment: @khmarbaise no special reason.It's Project requirement

Comment: Sorry to say that. But this stupid not to follow those conventions cause that will cause more configuration than you usually need and which in consequence cost money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep this in a single place you need to set the `testClassesDirectory` argument of the maven-surefire-plugin configuration:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <testClassesDirectory>path/to/compiled test classes</testClassesDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

All of this is well documented in the [Maven Surefire Plugin Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin)